# How to add a watermark to a viewport render?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Is it possible to add a watermark to the Viewport Render (solid)?

Currently, I use a text object parented close to the camera. This is not ideal, since I don't use the Blender default font, it keeps losing its path and its shading interferes with lighting.

I tried adding a Background Image to the camera, which sort of works. But it disappears when hiding the overlays.

Comment: what do you mean by "loosing its path"? if it is parented...it will always follow the camera...!?

Comment: @Chris I meant the path of where the font file is stored. When I moved the file to another directory or I sent it to someone else, Blender can't find the font anymore and goes back to the default font.

Comment: did you try to "file -> external data -> pack resources" before sending them to others?  i did not try that but this would be my first try...

Comment: I did, and that's works. But when I sent the file to someone else? And this isn't ideal either, since I don't own the font and I'm not allowed to distribute it. That's why I was looking for other options. Adding a background image to the camera works. But then I have to disable all other overlays by hand, easy to forget one.

Comment: you can use any other custom "free" font....just replace it and upload your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the text this material setup:

[image]

so it is not dependent on lights.

And for viewport display just assign a color here:

[image]

Comment: I've tested this, but still when the camera changes positions. The font interacts with lighting. The font is white but turns gray.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Blender's [Metadata](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/metadata.html).

In properties editor > Output tab > Metadata panel:

- disable all but "Note" metadata, write whatever watermark you want here
- enable burn into image
- do test renders to see the result and tweak the font size and colors to your liking.